# FactoryBoy - nested factories / max depth?

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I am writing tests for a large Django application, as part of this process I am gradually creating factories for all models of the different apps within the Django project.

However, I've run into some confusing behavior with FactoryBoy where it almost seems like `SubFactories` have an max depth beyond which no instances are generated.

The error occurs when I try to run the following test:

```
    def test_subfactories(self):
        """ Verify that the factory is able to initialize """
        user = UserFactory()
        self.assertTrue(user)
        self.assertTrue(user.profile)
        self.assertTrue(user.profile.tenant)

        order = OrderFactory()
        self.assertTrue(order)
        self.assertTrue(order.user.profile.tenant)
```

The last line will fail (`AssertionError: None is not true`), running this test through a debugger reveals that indeed order.user.profile.tenant returns `None` instead of the expected `Tenant` instance.

There are quite a few factories / models involved here, but the layout is relatively simple.

The `User` (django default) and the `Profile` model are linked through a OneToOneField, which (after some trouble) is represented by the `UserFactory` and `ProfileFactory`

```
@factory.django.mute_signals(post_save)
class ProfileFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = yuza_models.Profile
        django_get_or_create = ('user',)

    user = factory.SubFactory('yuza.factories.UserFactory')
    birth_date = factory.Faker('date_of_birth')
    street = factory.Faker('street_name')
    house_number = factory.Faker('building_number')
    city = factory.Faker('city')
    country = factory.Faker('country')
    avatar_file = factory.django.ImageField(color='blue')
    tenant = factory.SubFactory(TenantFactory)
```

```
@factory.django.mute_signals(post_save)
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = auth_models.User

    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "user_%d" % n)
    first_name = factory.Faker('first_name')
    last_name = factory.Faker('last_name')

    email = factory.Faker('email')
    is_staff = False
    is_superuser = False
    is_active = True
    last_login = factory.LazyFunction(timezone.now)

    @factory.post_generation
    def profile(self, create, extracted):
        if not create:
            return
        if extracted is None:
            ProfileFactory(user=self)
```

The `TenantFactory` below is represented as a `SubFactory` on the `ProfileFactory` above.

```
class TenantFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = elearning_models.Tenant

    name = factory.Faker('company')
    slug = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda obj: text.slugify(obj.name))
    name_manager = factory.Faker('name')
    title_manager = factory.Faker('job')
    street = factory.Faker('street_name')
    house_number = factory.Faker('building_number')
    house_number_addition = factory.Faker('secondary_address')
```

The `Order` is linked to a `User`, but many of its methods call fields of its `self.user.profile.tenant`

```
class OrderFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Order

    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    order_date = factory.LazyFunction(timezone.now)
    price = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: Decimal(random.uniform(1, 100)))
    site_tenant = factory.SubFactory(TenantFactory)
    no_tax = fuzzy.FuzzyChoice([True, False])
```

Again, most of the asserts in the test pass without failing, all separate factories are able to initialize fetch values from their immediate foreignkey relations. However, as soon as factories/models are three steps removed from each other the call will return None instead of the expected `Tenant` instance.

Since I was unable to find any reference to this behaviour in the FactoryBoy documentation its probably a bug on my side, but so far I've been unable to determine its origin. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**post_save method**

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        resume = profile.get_resume()
        resume.initialize()


post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: Add the OrderFactory code

Comment: Good catch, I fixed my example - thanks!

Comment: Wild guess: try `order.refresh_from_db()` before the assertions. Also are there any custom `save` methods in those models? PostGeneration (your `User.profile`) includes a call to `instance.save()` before finishing. Do the tables for `Profile` and `Tenant` hold anything/what you would expect?

Comment: I can't shake the feeling that something is off with `UserFactory.profile` (yes I am aware that the fault _appears_ to be with `ProfileFactor.tenant`). Does the test  pass if you use the earlier created user instance: `order = OrderFactory(user = user)` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response!

- including ```.refresh_from_db()``` before the assert did not pass
- order = OrderFactory(user = user) does pass!
- Order has a custom save method to set some datefields on save, but disabling this method did not change anything
- Your comments about UserProfile did lead me to further examine the `Profile` object, there exists a post_save method (included in my post above) that created a `Profile` on `User` creation.  I accounted for this signal by using the  `@factory.django.mute_signals` decorater on both the `UserFactory` and the `ProfileFactory`

Comment: When I applied this decorater to the `OrderFactory` as well the tests passed!

I had assumed that any calls on `Order.user` would trigger the `UserFactory` which had already been enclosed with the decorator - but evidently this wasnt enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, I've discovered the source of the problem: the `post-save` method linked to the `UserProfile` (I've included the code in my post).

This `post-save` method created a `Profile` on `User` creation. I accounted for this signal by using the `@factory.django.mute_signals` decorater on both the `UserFactory`and the `ProfileFactory`.

I had assumed that any calls on `Order.user` would trigger the `UserFactory` which had already been enclosed with the decorator, but this is not assumption proved to be wrong. Only when I applied the decorated to the `OrderFactory` as well did the tests pass.

Thus the `@factory.django.mute_signals` decorator should not just be used on factories that are affected by these signals, but also on any factory that is using those factories as a `SubFactory`!